# lightning:recordEditForm QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED error on page load

Tags: lightning, error-messages, lightning-recordeditform

We're intermittently receiving a QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED error when loading data on the lightning:recordEditForm. I see a solution on here for LWC's lightning forms, but haven't quite figured out a way to workaround this issue on an Aura component.

It took me quite a bit of debugging but we're displaying this error from the lightning:recordEditForm's onerror handler. Is there a way we can avoid this issue without trying to remove formula fields? As far as I can tell we don't really have a large amount of fields overall nor do we have that many formulas, though there are several that are complex.

I believe it occurs when we attempt to reload the form after save.

[image: This record could not be loaded because it includes too many formula fields with complex formulas, or too many custom fields. Ask your Salesforce admnistrator to remove some formula fields or simplify the formulas in use.]
Error message: "This record could not be loaded because it includes too many formula fields with complex formulas, or too many custom fields. Ask your Salesforce admnistrator to remove some formula fields or simplify the formulas in use."

```
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditFormLine" objectApiName="OrderItem" recordId="{!v.orderItem.Id}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" onload="{!c.onLoad}"  onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onerror="{!c.handleError}">
```

Comment: Can you specify the fields to load instead of a layout="FULL"? That would help you control how much is being loaded.

Comment: Added the code snippet of what runs. IIRC, we don't specify layout in a recordEditForm.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of the other lightning data load thing. So... yeah, your page layout is probably too complicated, need to simplify the fields you have on it. We had this problem in our org for Accounts.

Comment: What are the best ways to simplify it? There are quite a few fields we need, but where should I start in terms of removing fields? Behind the scenes, the short message for the error is "QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED", so is it better to focus on formula fields? It's not like we have a ton of fields on this page layout... Less than 100 for sure.

Comment: Yes, complicated formulas are the number one cause of this exception. You can use workflow rules to calculate values and store them in fields to reduce formula complexity, optimizing formulas to be as minimal as possible, not use formulas in formulas, etc.

Comment: Thank you. A couple of follow up questions:
1. Would we expect this error to show up on the Apex side if it were the case?
2. Is this with respect to just the formulas that might be on the page layout or all formula fields?

Comment: (1) No, it's a Lightning issue (2) only the fields on the page layout. Note that simply having too many fields *at all* can cause this error. For example, if you have 700 text fields on your page layout, you'll likely get this error, even with no formulas. Formulas simply cause this error to happen sooner. Reducing the number of fields on your page may be necessary.

Comment: I have also found that this is a known issue in Salesforce right now: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HgFG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually due to a Salesforce known issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001lUqTQAU

This was fixed in the Winter 21 Release.